# How is consensus reached in a Decentralized Oracle Network?

Tags: blockchain, oracles, consensus

I understand the deterministic nature of blockchains thus the need for oracles to feed outputs of non deterministic algorithms or API-calls to smart contracts.  Using a single node oracle would defeat the purpose of using a blockchain, A DON (decentralized Oracle Network) is used instead.

I understand that a consensus mechanism is used to agree on a given blockchain state at a given timestamp. In an Oracle Problem scenario though a DON output would serve as an input in determining the updated blockchain state. How is consensus reached in a DON in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Answered by Joose#0001 on Chainlink official discord](https://discord.com/channels/592041321326182401/605768708266131456/1102229469751689237)

Chainlink consensus is an interesting topic.

TLDR: Chainlink nodes coordinate and talk to each other using a Byzantine Fault Tolerant "sleepy" consensus mechanism.

If you want details, read the 3 articles I link below (from the CL website), in order.

If you want more details, read the 2 Chainlink white papers!

[1) "Minority Corruption Resilience in Byzantine Generals With Unknown and Fluctuating Participation"](https://blog.chain.link/minority-corruption-resilience-in-byzantine-generals-with-unknown-and-fluctuating-participation/)

[2) "The Latest View on View Synchronization"](https://blog.chain.link/view-synchronization/)

[3) "Optimal Latency and Communication SMR View-Synchronization"](https://blog.chain.link/optimal-latency-and-communication-smr-view-synchronization/)